# Must I cite my own code when writing academic papers?

Tags: citations

I am writing a work-term report in scientific paper format and I've been citing all software and source code that I have used in my project, but when it comes to scripts I have written, must I create citations for those as well?

It may be worth noting that all the code itself is not central to the paper, only that I've used it during my project (bioinformatics).

Comment: You should attach all the Codes that you used (a.k.a created) for that Project, regardless of their significance. If they are part of the project they should be part of the paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. It might be on-topic at the [academics.se] site.